# Print newlines on command output

Tags: bash, command-line

If I get the result of a command on a variable, how can I print this output with new lines. Silly example:

```
XX=$(ls -l); echo $XX
```

When I execute the above sentence, I have one line ilegible result instead of a formatted return as I saw when `ls -l` is executed on a terminal. Is there any way to get the result of a command formatted or to display it's result with newlines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need double quotes to make the shells don't perform [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05):

```
XX="$(ls -l)"; echo "$XX"
```

But it's not good to use `echo` with variable that you don't know its content, you should use `printf` (read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819)) instead:

```
XX="$(ls -l)"; printf '%s\n' "$XX"
```

Comment: What is dangerous about echoing a string?

Comment: @glennjackman: No dangerous, it's just `printf` is better than `echo`. Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819.